# Cast() exception: LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, casting, linq-to-entities

I want to display some entity named `CriminalEvent` in a general-purpose MVC view I wrote. The view requires that the Model pass to it shall implement the `IDataModel` interface. Now, `CriminalEvent` has the properties to implement this interface but under a different name and I cannot change it.

So in my code I inherited `CriminalEvent` and my derived class (also called CriminalEvent, stupid I guess but allows me to avoid many code changes...) has explicit interface code:

```
Using ViewApp;
public interface IDataModel
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int CriminalEventID { get; set; }
}

public class ViewCriminalEvent : AIM.Police.DB.CriminalEvent, IDataModel
{
    int IDataModel.ID
    {
        get { return CriminalEventID; }
        set { CriminalEventID = value; }
    }
}
```

(I know, in this case the interface's ID property equals CriminalEventID, it's Ok)

I expected to be able to read the `AIM.Police.DB.CriminalEvent` Entities and populate my view model by Linq to Entities Cast()ing them to the derived `CriminalEvent`, like this:

The view model (I need to populate the `CriminalEvents` property):

```
Using ViewApp;
public class CriminalEventMainViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<IDataModel> CriminalEvents { get; set; }
    public IDataModel SelectedEntity { get; set; }

    public string SubEntityDisplayName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IDataModel> SubEntityCollection { get; set; }
    public IDataModel SelectedSubEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and the Controller code:

```
Using ViewApp;    
private ViewResult CriminalEventIndexView(CriminalEvent selectedCriminalEvent = null)
{
    CriminalEventMainViewModel viewModel =
        new CriminalEventMainViewModel();

    using (var db1 = new AIM.Police.DB.InvestigationContext(lazyLoadingEnabled: false))
    {
        viewModel.CriminalEvents = db1.CriminalEvents.Cast<ViewCriminalEvent>().ToList(); // THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION
        viewModel.SelectedEntity = selectedCriminalEvent;
    }
    return View("Index", (object)viewModel);
}
```

Note both the original `CriminalEvent` class and the `InvestigationContext` are found in the AIM.Police.DB dll that I cannot touch

The Error:

`Unable to cast the type 'AIM.Police.DB.CriminalEvent' to type 'InvestigationSimulator.Models.CriminalEvent'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

Why do I get this error?
Remarks on my approach are always welcome..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're getting all of the entities, you could materialize the query first, then perform the cast.

This would perform the Cast in memory instead of trying to formulate it as part of the query translation.  The error comes because LINQ to Entities doesn't support transforming the SQL to a non-entity class, even when it inherits from an entity class, because there is no mapping for the additional columns to the `SELECT` statement.  By materializing the data, then performing the `Cast` in memory (LINQ to Objects), you avoid the translation error.

However, in your case, you have the inheritance backwards for this to work. For it to work, I'd suggest having the DB model implement `IDataModel` and avoid the cast entirely, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738696(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx.  In particular, your partial class can implement the interface (honestly don't remember if the designer allows you to add an interface definition since I only do code-first these days). Note that may remove the need for your view-specific model entirely.

```
viewModel.CriminalEvents = db1.CriminalEvents.ToList();
```

The alternative, which I would probably do, is keep the view model completely separate (not have it inherit from the entity class) and use AutoMapper to map between them.

```
var criminalEvents = db1.CriminalEvents.ToList();
viewModel.CriminalEvents = Mapper.Map<CriminalEventViewModel>(criminalEvents);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just get `InvalidCastException`? `AIM.Police.DB.CriminalEvent` doesn't derive from `InvestigationSimulator.Models.CriminalEvent`. The question isn't clear (two `CriminalEvent` classes in different namespaces, and code using unqualified references without showing the `using` namespaces), but I think EF will be configured to return `AIM.Police.DB.CriminalEvent`, and in that case, it just won't work.

Comment: @hvd I interpreted the Cast as going the other way from the DB model to the view model. It really doesn't make sense any other way.  In that case the view model does derive from the DB model. The error message seems to reinforce this.  It is a bad practice, IMO, to have the classes named the same. In my Automapper example, I introduced a different naming for the view model to make the distinction more clear.

Comment: I'm also interpreting it as going from the DB model to the view model, but if that's from base to derived, it won't work. Agreed that your AutoMapper approach is probably better.

Comment: @hvd - wow - must not be thinking.  You're absolutely right. I was just trying to solve the specific error.  The inheritance needs to go the the other way as well.  I'll fix it up.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear code, the inheritance is from the DB model to the view model, and the code is `Using` the view model's namespace and so is any mention of `CriminalEvent` (except where explicitely stated `AIM.Police.DB`). I'll update the code above...

Comment: @tvanfosson - I never used AutoMapper. I thought using it would require defining a view model (class) and then specifying the mapping from each source (DB model) property to each dest (view model) property, which always seemed to me to be too much code with little profit. Is it not the case? And where do I (nu?)get this Mapper?

Comment: @user1707621 you can add AutoMapper and the MVC/WebAPI specific helpers using NuGet.  Yes, it normally does require a separate view model class, but it is quite smart about mapping properties with the same names and types so the configuration is usually minimal. The advantage of using separate view models is reduced coupling between your views and the your business entities plus the model can be tailored to the view, which could incorporate data from multiple models and yet remain flat.

Comment: @tvanfosson Though it's clear a View Model is the right thing to do generally, in my views I almost by definition need all properties. I never liked the idea of Mapping also. So I guess the right solution for my is the DB Model will implement the interface. It is justified since it's general enough and not specific to my viewApp (something like `IIdentifiable` I guess)

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.Cast<TResult>` is trying to cast every element in the collection. And it fails in your scenario (no surprise) because you are trying to cast instances of *parent* (`AIM.Police.DB.CriminalEvent`) class to objects of *child* (`InvestigationSimulator.Models.CriminalEvent`) class. You cannot do such casting in C#.

In order to fix this you will need to load objects from your DB first and then convert (map) them manually to your Model class. Easiest code is like this:

```
viewModel.CriminalEvents = db1.CriminalEvents.ToList().Select(ce => new InvestigationSimulator.Models.CriminalEvent() { Id = ce.Id, }).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList().Select(...)` essentially unnecessarily creates a list for a single enumeration. It should probably be either `ToList().ConvertAll(...)` or `AsEnumerable().Select(...)`. (The result of all three will be the same, only the way they get that result differs.)

Comment: @SergeyS, I admit I didn't know Casting works only Child -> Parent and not vice versa, anyway I guess I cannot avoid the mapping, right? The init of the `Id` prop in your Easiest Code is intended as an example and should be done for all properties of parent?

Comment: @user1707621 - Yes, you are right, this is just an example, you should init all properties you need there (just separated by comma). Note that your properties in Model can have different name/type, you will define mapping rules in the way which fits you best. There is no need to inherit your CriminalEvent Model class from DB one. Just define properties you really need in your app, and map only those from DB.

Comment: Casting in type inheritance works either direction. It only causes a runtime error if the object happens not to be the particular child.

Answer (score 1):

Use cast after ToList() or Single()

```
_c.Customers.ToList().Cast<CustomerBinding>()
```

Comment: Casting after ToList returns an IEnumerable.  Casting the ToList will return a properly typed list: `_c.Customers.ToList<CustomerBinding>()`